# Change GET request Variable inside while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to build an array of xml files.
Each get request gives me 100 products and I need to get around 800 products.

So I tried building a loop based on a variable ts_d which u can use to get the next page of the xml.

```
public function getXml($division, $topic, $tsp)
{   
    $array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $x = 1;
    while ($x = 1) {
        $headers = ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->getAccessToken()];
        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/',
        ]);
        try {
            $response = $client->request('GET', 'XMLDownload.aspx', [
                'query' => ['Topic' => $topic, '_Division_' => $division, 'TSPaging' => $tsp],
                'headers' => $headers,
            ]);
            $string = new \SimpleXMLElement((string) $response->getBody());
            $tspaging = $string->Topics->Topic->attributes()->{'ts_d'};
            $array[$i]=$string;
            echo $tspaging . '   ' . $tsp;
        } 
        catch (\Exception $e) {}
        if (!isset($tspaging)) {
            $x = 0;
        }
        $i++;
        $tsp = $tspaging
        unset($string);

    }
    return $array;
}
```

I call this function with:

```
$stockPositions = $connection->getXml(1310477, 'StockPositions', '');
```

But this while loop is infinite and the echo returns:

```
    0x000000000F5753AB   0x000000000F5753AB   0x000000000F5753AB0x000000000F5753AB   0x000000000F5753AB0x000000000F5753AB   0x000000000F5753AB0x000000000F5753AB   0x000000000F5753AB0x000000000F5753AB
```

Can you guys help met get out of this infinite loop?

Comment: `while ($x = 1)` ? don't you mean `==` ? also, it seems like `$x` should be a boolean `true`/`false` as you use it...

Comment: changed the while loop to ($x), $x = 1 to true and the if statement to false but the result is the same.

Comment: You need to test for variable 'tspaging'  and verify that is this actually falling inside Exception Catch block where you are terminating the script?

Comment: Your exit condition is about `$tspaging`. What happens to make it not set ? You are calling multiples pages, and in each page, there is a tag for the next page number, is that correct ? You have to debug what is the XML you receive, and why $tspaging is always set... (maybe unset it at the end of the while loop ?)

Comment: The problem was that $tspaging was returning a simpleXmlObject string instead of a normal string.

The solution was adding strval to that element:
    $tspaging = strval($string->Topics->Topic->attributes()->{'ts_d'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that $tspaging was returning a simpleXmlObject string instead of a normal string. The solution was adding strval to that element:

```
$tspaging = strval($string->Topics->Topic->attributes()->{'ts_d'});
```